# Get Duplicate Value on Inner Join Statment on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, inner-join

I Have an inner join statement to get id which run on the 3 process and logged on three table,

```
Select  a.InquiryAccount ,a.InquiryAmount,a.InquiryCustName,a.InquiryLang, b.PayAmountPaid,b.PayScreenText,b.PayReceiptText, c.RevRefNo
from
    inquiry a
        inner join
    Payment b
        on a.InquiryAccount = b.PayAccount
        inner join 
    Reversal c
        on a.InquiryAccount = c.RevAccount

order by c.RevRefNo desc
```

and it give the result like i want, but theres some value which doubled or duplicate, and i want to track which account who duplicate on inner join reult.

i try to do something like this on my inner join :

```
SELECT *
FROM Inquiry
WHERE InquiryAccount IN (
 SELECT InquiryAccount
 FROM Inquiry
 GROUP BY InquiryAccount 
 HAVING (COUNT(InquiryAccount ) > 1)
)
```

which show the only account which duplicate.
but when i try `group by` on the `Inner Join` its get an error, is it possible to `group by` on `inner join`? or are there any solutions on found duplicate value on `inner join`statment?

here's the result of my inner join statment :

```
InquiryAccount  InquiryAmount   InquiryLang
    10176601              124070    0
    12344556              160050    1
    10445654              160050    1
    23456789              160050    1
    22456666              160050    1
    45324681              160050    1
    14356890              160050    1
    44566666              160050    1
    22456666              160050    1
    10176601              160050    1
```

here's the sample that i want to produce from my inner join statment , which only get the duplicate account :

```
InquiryAccount  InquiryAmount   InquiryLang
10176601              124070    0
10176601              160050    1
22456666              160050    1
22456666              160050    1
```

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: @JW웃 i already give a simple records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.InquiryAccount
        ,a.InquiryAmount
        ,a.InquiryCustName
        ,a.InquiryLang
        ,b.PayAmountPaid
        ,b.PayScreenText
        ,b.PayReceiptText
        ,c.RevRefNo 
FROM dbo.inquiry a 
JOIN dbo.Payment b ON a.InquiryAccount = b.PayAccount 
JOIN dbo.Reversal c ON a.InquiryAccount = c.RevAccount
ORDER BY c.RevRefNo DESC
```